# R: recover function call from an object

Tags: r, function

```
ctl <- c(4.17,5.58,5.18,6.11,4.50,4.61,5.17,4.53,5.33,5.14)
trt <- c(4.81,4.17,4.41,3.59,5.87,3.83,6.03,4.89,4.32,4.69)
group <- gl(2, 10, 20, labels = c("Ctl","Trt"))
weight <- c(ctl, trt)
lm.D9 <- lm(weight ~ group)
lm.D90 <- lm(weight ~ group - 1) # omitting intercept

> lm.D90

Call:
lm(formula = weight ~ group)

Coefficients:
  (Intercept)     groupTrt  
      5.032       -0.371
```

I have a `lm` function here, and if I simply look at the object, `lm.D90`, I can see the exact call I used, which is `lm(formula = weight ~ group)`. Currently I have some objects whose calls I would like to recover. Is there a generic function in R that returns the call from which the object was obtained?

Comment: The call element of your linear model `lm.D90$call` (?)

Comment: This can be done only if the object is constructed to include function call. In its implementation. Function  `lm` gets the call with `match.call()` and places the result in its own result object along with other data. So we can probably do it if we are creating the object in a function, otherwise it would depend on the implementation of the function that is generating the object.

Comment: I see. Thank you.